# sort() sorts data by the first digit, not the whole number

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I have a sorting method that I want to sort my divs based on their `data-position` attribute. At the moment, for some reason the function sorts the divs based only on the first digit, and not the whole number. Here is an example in my `html` which shows that:

**html**

```
<div class="parent" data-position="1">
    ...
</div>

<div class="parent" data-position="27">
    ...
</div>

<div class="parent" data-position="3">
    ...
</div>
```

Here's the **js**

```
$('body').on('click', '.new_comments', function(e) {
    var divArr = $(".parent");
    divArr.sort(function(a, b) {
        return $(a).attr('data-position') > $(b).attr('data-position') ? 1: -1;
    });
$(".comments_container").append(divArr);

});
```

Any idea why it does this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(a).attr('data-position')
```

Attr returns the attribute value as a string, so you're comparison is comparing strings, not numbers, which is what you are expecting I assume.  Instead of using attr() use data().

```
$(a).data('position')
```

The difference between the two is that jQuery will try to auto convert the value in the attribute to a number if it can when you use `data()`.  So with the values converted to numbers, you should see the sorting you expect.

Answer (score 3):

Convert the string data to numbers.

```js
$('body').on('click', 'button', function(e) {
  var divArr = $(".parent");
  
  divArr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return +$(a).attr('data-position') > +$(b).attr('data-position') ? 1 : -1;
  });

  $(".comments_container").append(divArr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK ME</button>

<div class="comments_container">
  <div class="parent" data-position="1">
    1 </div> 
  <div class="parent" data-position="27">  27  </div> 
  <div class="parent" data-position="3"> 3 </div>
</div>
```

And I would first gather the attributes instead of doing it repeatedly in the callback.

```js
$('body').on('click', 'button', function(e) {
  $(".parent")
    .map((i, el) => ({el: el, pos: +el.dataset.position}))
    .sort((a, b) => a.pos > b.pos ? 1 : -1)
    .map((i, {el}) => el)
    .appendTo(".comments_container");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK ME</button>

<div class="comments_container">
  <div class="parent" data-position="1"> 1 </div> 
  <div class="parent" data-position="27">  27  </div> 
  <div class="parent" data-position="3"> 3 </div>
</div>
```

I also included some modern syntax in this solution